# Metadata Quick Navigation - Expand Termset programmtically

Tags: 2010, mms

I use SP 2010 and I have a metadata Termset which is shown in the quick navigation inside a list. I would like to expand it automatically when the site is loading. I tried using JS and a content editor webpart. I used the following JS snippet:

```
javascript:TreeView_PopulateNode(ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ctl01_WebTreeView_Data,1,ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ctl01_WebTreeViewn1,ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ctl01_WebTreeViewt1,ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ctl01_WebTreeViewt1i,' ','Kategorie','Dateien\\Kategorie','t','30:FieldNameNode:2d4b592e-cfb3-4794-a2e6-8b4091e5f707:d62b4acc-3587-4548-88f0-c3fb9b36902c:8ddc6c4e-07f6-4781-86ae-89890d7c2daf:30|ListNode|2d4b592e-cfb3-4794-a2e6-8b4091e5f707|d62b4acc-3587-4548-88f0-c3fb9b36902c|dee2f67f-95c6-411c-8683-16a09963ffcd','tt')
```

However, since the IDs change everytime I rebuild the page with my Powershell script (which I use to build the page), the code won't work the next time I use the script. Is there another way to do it programmtically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes...You can do it in C#.

Here's an example.

http://roy-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/02/sharepoint-add-terms-to-metadata-store.html

```
private void setTagsToDirectory()
{
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site-url"))
          {
TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
TermStore termStore = session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
Group group = termStore.Groups["Test Terms"];
TermSet termSet = group.TermSets["Testing"];
try
{
Term keywordTerm;
keywordTerm = termSet.CreateTerm("apple", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
termStore.CommitAll();
}
catch (Exception)
{
//Term already exist in the current term set
}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think you know what I want. The terms are created. I just want to expand the menu (like when you click on the arrow next to the termset) in the navigation.

Comment: I'm sorry. I must have misread your question.

You're wanting the menu to show by default without having to mouse over, correct?

Comment: Yep, without having to click on the little arrow.

Comment: You'll need to use CSS then. Use Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in IE to mouse-over the object you want to show and then change the properties using CSS so that the item is displayed.